# awk: set desired number of columns?

Tags: awk

I'm parsing a simple conf file of the following format:

```
key = value
```

To do this, I use `awk` like

```
KEY=$(awk -F' *= *' '/^key/{print $2}' file.conf)
```

However, some values might containt `=` symbol, so what I want is basically to tell `awk` that I need only two columns, i.e. force it to accept everything it encounters after the first separator as one column. I didn't find such option. How can I do that?

Comment: do you want to store key or value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the separator can appear inside fields, then it's not really a separator. I'd use something like

```
KEY=$(sed -n '/^key *=/ { s/^key *= *//; p }' file.conf)
```

instead: this looks for lines starting with `key` followed by any number of spaces and an `=` sign, drops the start of the line and prints it. As [dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085) points out the `p` can be conditioned on the `s`:

```
KEY=$(sed -n 's/^key *= *//p' file.conf)
```

The equivalent AWK is

```
KEY=$(awk '/^key *=/ { sub("^key *= *", ""); print }' file.conf)
```

and the same combining trick can be used:

```
KEY=$(awk 'sub("^key *= *", "")' file.conf)
```

Comment: Or just `sed -n 's/^key *= *//p'` which prints only if the substitution succeeded. Similarly awk `sub` returns 1 iff successful and can be used as a condition with default action `print`. (`gsub` returns count, but is no use here because this pattern can only match once.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Nice, thanks — I thought of the AWK variant as I was updating too ;-).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 in effect both `sub()` and `gsub()` return the count, it's just that `sub()` is limited to one replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Just another variant, this time with grep:

```
KEY=$(grep -Po  '^key\s*=\s*\K.*'  f.conf )
```

Answer (score 0):

just takeout the first column value

```
KEY=$(awk -F= '{$1="";sub("=","")}1' OFS="=" file.conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by using this command:

```
KEY=$(awk -F 'key *= *' '{print $2}' f.conf)
```