# Awk print columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

So I'm trying to parse data into a different format, but the last columns data contains the separator.

If I use:

```
awk -F: {' print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 '}
```

and the data is:

```
ExampleCol1:ExampleCol2:Ex:am:ple:Col3
```

I only get:

```
ExampleCol1    ExampleCol2    Ex
```

How can I grab the rest of the columns after `$2`? So something like:

```
print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $(REST OF COLUMNS)
```

Comment: Related: [awk: set desired number of columns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328072/awk-set-desired-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly does this work for you?

```
sed -e 's/:/\t/1' -e 's/:/\t/1' yourFile
```

It replaces the first two colons with tabs and prints the rest

With your sample data the output is

```
ExampleCol1    ExampleCol2    Ex:am:ple:Col3
```

I'm unsure since in your question you say you get

```
ExampleCol1:ExampleCol2:Ex
```

When executing the awk command you provided I get

```
ExampleCol1    ExampleCol2    Ex
```

Comment: Hey this should work, I'll run a test now & yeah sorry I miswrote the expected output

Comment: Well it worked to the extent that it replaces the first two seperators ":" as tabs, but if there's data infront of those it outputs to the destination file. Example line - 1:ExampleCol1:ExampleCol2:Ex:am:ple:Col3 

Which would output 1   ExampleCol1    Example2    Ex:am:...

but I only want the 2 specific cols and rest of col 4 in this case

Comment: I will mark it as working though, as it works for that format & I can also make slight changes in order to get it working for other formats :), so thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! If it saves you any time I think the modification you want for this other format would be to switch both 1's to 2's

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
_example='ExampleCol1:ExampleCol2:Ex:am:ple:Col3'

awk -F: '{printf $1 "\t" $2 "\t"} {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf $i "\t"} {print ""}' <<<"${_example}"
```

... looks a little messy but will output...

```
ExampleCol1 ExampleCol2 Ex  am  ple Col3
```

... there's likely a more succinct way to express what ya want with `awk` eg...

```bsh
awk -F: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $i "\t"} {print ""}' <<<"$_example"
```

... but the above should get ya a little closer to the desired behavior with `awk`

### Update

Oh looks like ya might have wanted the colons after the second column, if so then...

```bsh
awk -F: '{printf $1 "\t" $2 "\t"} {for(i=3;i<NF;i++) printf $i ":"} {print $NF}' <<<"$_example"
```

... might be a little more correct for answering this with `awk`...

```
ExampleCol1 ExampleCol2 Ex:am:ple:Col3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way out could be as shown:

```
 $ awk -vOFS="\t" '{
     sub(/:/, OFS)
     sub(/:/, OFS)
 }1' inp
```

Or, as another way:

```
 $ awk '! /:.*:/ || sub(/:/, "\t") && sub(/:/, "\t")' inp
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

command

```
 sed "s/:/ /3g" filename| awk -F ":" '{print $1,$2,$3}'| sed "s/ /:/3g"| awk 'OFS="\t" {print $1,$2,$3}'
```

output

```
ExampleCol1 ExampleCol2 Ex:am:ple:Col3
```